# JSON Parsing and recieved : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, json, parsing, null, fatal-error

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let reposURL = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=AIzaSyC4BR5rZLNkeGChLr8N00BHZqBYqPdrgjg&location=43.690578,-79.342348&radius=400&types=cafe|bakery")
    // 2
    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL!) {
        // 3
        if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
            // 4
            if let reposArray = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                // 5
                for item in reposArray {
                    repositories.append(Repository(json: item))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

receiving a exc_bad_instruction error @ line 5 and not sure why, its saying im force unwrapping nil but the URL is working and i can open it in my browser without an issue and see all the JSON data

Comment: I Checked the URL response.But there is no key as "items"

Comment: you write this way `json["results"]` because url return "result" in dictionary. @YMK

Comment: Do not share your API Key to public

Comment: @iOS i planned on changing it anyways, thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode your URL with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` :

```
var urlstr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=AIzaSyC4BR5rZLNkeGChLr8N00BHZqBYqPdrgjg&location=43.690578,-79.342348&radius=400&types=cafe|bakery"

var escapedString = urlstr.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let reposURL = NSURL(string: escapedString!)
// 2
if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL!) {
    // 3
    if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {
        // 4
        print(json)
        if let reposArray = json["results"] as? [NSDictionary] {
            // 5
            for item in reposArray {
                print(item)// You will get particular items 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will get your JSON response.

In the response there is no parameters like `items`.

So, after the `print(json)` check the response and get the data by the parameters.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Ok cool thanks a lot. This fixed the error, now to just figure out why the data isn't getting placed into the table view

Comment: @YMK you have to create an array as globally fill the reposArray in it. I have updated answer with the results array of dictionary. check the update and reload the table view after setting the data.

Answer (score 0):

With **Swift 2** the signature for NSJSONSerialization has changed, to conform to the new error handling system. Here is the same answer as @ashish-kakkad proposed, but updated to **Swift 2**

```
    var urlstr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=AIzaSyC4BR5rZLNkeGChLr8N00BHZqBYqPdrgjg&location=43.690578,-79.342348&radius=400&types=cafe|bakery"

        var escapedString = urlstr.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let reposURL = NSURL(string: escapedString!)
        // 2
        if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: reposURL!) {
            // 3
                do {
                    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        // 4
                        print(json)
                        if let reposArray = json["results"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                            // 5
                            for item in reposArray {
                                print(item)// You will get particular items
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
        }
```